# Check to see if an int minus an int is equal to a multiple of an int

Tags: java, int

Is it possible to see if an integer minus an integer is equal to a multiple of another integer? If I has three integers x, y, and z, could I see if x - y = a multiple of z? Here is an example:

```
if (x - y == multiple of z) {//do stuff}
```

If x is 20, y is 5, and z  is 5, how would I see if x minus y is equal to z or equal to a multiple of z if that is possible.

Comment: If `y` is a multiple of `z`, then `y % z == 0`.

Comment: @Amadan: Well, unless `y` and `z` are both zero but now I'm just being a pedant :-)